# Renew Link showing - The page you requested is currently unavailable

Tags: wordpress, civimember, error-page

The affected renewing members are getting

"Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. The page you requested is currently unavailable. Return to home page."

When attempting to click the Renew Now button from the dashboard.

Comment: It doesn't show this for all people only some. Credentials are not different between affected users and unaffected users.

Comment: Tiffany - it would possibly help if you provided some example urls - do they change if a person is logged in or not?

Comment: These are the links shown on the account dashboard. They have to be logged in for that. The link takes them to DOMAIN/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=1&mid=62&reset=1 

I can perform this task in the administrator account fine, and I have further tried other accounts without issue. I have checked to see if it is an account permissions issue and this problem persists even when set to full admin

Comment: Were the memberships originally created via the Contribution pages or via the back end admin. I think it is (or was) the case that for a membership to be able to be renewed via a public page it needs to have been associated with a specific Contribution Page ID. Is it possible that the ones that are 'failing' are ones that were originally created at the backend? If so I will convert this to an answer but meanwhile hope it gives you another avenue to persue

Comment: HMMM maybe. Let me see.

Comment: Both members that have recently complained were self created through a membership contribution page. Oh you know what. I switched pages at one point because one stopped sending membership receipts. I wonder if the disabled page makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For this case the originating contribution PageIDs were disabled. Once re-enabled the renewal button worked fine.

Comment: Glad that pointer helped.